# How to align outputLabel and selectOneMenu in a panelGrid

Tags: css, primefaces

I need to make a simple align using **p:outputLabel** and **p:selectOneMenu** like this basic [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/panelGrid.jsf)

But, it's just working when I using p:inputText.

I need something like this:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">

    <h:outputLabel for="idName" value="* #{msg.select_name}: " required="true" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="idSName" value="#{manage.name}">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{manage.listNames}"  />
    </p:selectOneMenu> 

    <h:outputLabel for="idCountry" value="#{msg.select_country}: " required="true" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="idCountryCustomer" value="#{manage.countrySelected}">  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{manage.listCountryCustomer}"  />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>

</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific than "it's just not working." What isn't working? Are you getting an error? Does the output look wrong? Do you have the proper backing beans (msg and manage)? You may want to include the relevant methods from those beans.

Comment: He has two components and he want them aligned. Pretty clear to me and beans are not relevant imo.

Comment: Yes, @KarlKildén. I just want aligned the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `for="idName"` in your `<h:outputLabel>`, however the id of `<p:selectOneMenu>` is "idSName". The names have to match.

You may also try `<p:outputLabel>` instead of `<h:outputLabel>`.

Answer (score 4):

On `p:selectOneMenu` you should apply `vertical-align:middle`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="idSName" value="#{manage.name}" style="vertical-align:middle;">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{manage.listNames}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```